# Android Studio from SQLite Database to other activities ListView

Tags: android, sqlite, listview, android-activity, android-sqlite

Sorry if this is turns out to be stupid. I'm trying to get some data from the user in one activity that has 3 EditText fields, title, description and routine, put it into an SQLite database (and yes I do use a DBAdapter), and then show it in another activities list view. The problem is that after I fill in the fields and press the save button that calls the onClick_AddTask function and then returns you to the list view activity, there is no obvious error but the list view is empty. I do get some errors in the logcat though but I cant really understand it. Any sort of insight or constructive criticism is always welcome, and thanks.

DBAdapter :

```
import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
import android.util.Log;

public class DBAdapter {

private static final String TAG = "DBAdapter"; //used for logging database version changes

// Field Names:
public static final String KEY_ROWID = "_id";
public static final String KEY_TASK = "task";
public static final String KEY_DESCRIPTION = "description";
public static final String KEY_DATE = "date";
public static final String KEY_EXERCISES = "exercises";

public static final String[] ALL_KEYS = new String[] {KEY_ROWID, KEY_TASK, KEY_DESCRIPTION, KEY_DATE, KEY_EXERCISES};

// Column Numbers for each Field Name:
public static final int COL_ROWID = 0;
public static final int COL_TASK = 1;
public static final int COL_DATE = 2;
public static final int COL_DESCRIPTION = 3;
public static final int COL_EXERCISES = 4;

// DataBase info:
public static final String DATABASE_NAME = "dbToDo";
public static final String DATABASE_TABLE = "mainToDo";
public static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 3; // The version number must be incremented each time a change to DB structure occurs.

//SQL statement to create database
private static final String DATABASE_CREATE_SQL = 
        "CREATE TABLE " + DATABASE_TABLE 
        + " (" + KEY_ROWID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, "
        + KEY_TASK + " TEXT NOT NULL, "
        + KEY_DATE + " TEXT, "
        + KEY_DESCRIPTION + " TEXT, "
        + KEY_EXERCISES + " TEXT"
        + ");";

private final Context context;
private DatabaseHelper myDBHelper;
private SQLiteDatabase db;


public DBAdapter(Context ctx) {
    this.context = ctx;
    myDBHelper = new DatabaseHelper(context);
}

// Open the database connection.
public DBAdapter open() {
    db = myDBHelper.getWritableDatabase();
    return this;
}

// Close the database connection.
public void close() {
    myDBHelper.close();
}

// Add a new set of values to be inserted into the database.
public long insertRow(String task, String date, String description, String exercises) {
    ContentValues initialValues = new ContentValues();
    initialValues.put(KEY_TASK, task);
    initialValues.put(KEY_DATE, date);
    initialValues.put(KEY_DESCRIPTION, description);
    initialValues.put(KEY_EXERCISES, exercises);


    // Insert the data into the database.
    return db.insert(DATABASE_TABLE, null, initialValues);
}

// Delete a row from the database, by rowId (primary key)
public boolean deleteRow(long rowId) {
    String where = KEY_ROWID + "=" + rowId;
    return db.delete(DATABASE_TABLE, where, null) != 0;
}

public void deleteAll() {
    Cursor c = getAllRows();
    long rowId = c.getColumnIndexOrThrow(KEY_ROWID);
    if (c.moveToFirst()) {
        do {
            deleteRow(c.getLong((int) rowId));              
        } while (c.moveToNext());
    }
    c.close();
}

// Return all data in the database.
public Cursor getAllRows() {
    String where = null;
    Cursor c =  db.query(true, DATABASE_TABLE, ALL_KEYS, where, null, null, null, null, null);
    if (c != null) {
        c.moveToFirst();
    }
    return c;
}

// Get a specific row (by rowId)
public Cursor getRow(long rowId) {
    String where = KEY_ROWID + "=" + rowId;
    Cursor c =  db.query(true, DATABASE_TABLE, ALL_KEYS, 
                    where, null, null, null, null, null);
    if (c != null) {
        c.moveToFirst();
    }
    return c;
}

// Change an existing row to be equal to new data.
public boolean updateRow(long rowId, String task, String date) {
    String where = KEY_ROWID + "=" + rowId;
    ContentValues newValues = new ContentValues();
    newValues.put(KEY_TASK, task);
    newValues.put(KEY_DATE, date);
    // Insert it into the database.
    return db.update(DATABASE_TABLE, newValues, where, null) != 0;
}


private static class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper
{
    DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase _db) {
        _db.execSQL(DATABASE_CREATE_SQL);           
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase _db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        Log.w(TAG, "Upgrading application's database from version " + oldVersion
                + " to " + newVersion + ", which will destroy all old data!");

        // Destroy old database:
        _db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + DATABASE_TABLE);

        // Recreate new database:
        onCreate(_db);
    }
}
```

}

Main Activity :

```
import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.support.v4.widget.SimpleCursorAdapter;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.widget.ButtonBarLayout;
import android.text.TextUtils;
import android.text.format.Time;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.util.List;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

Time today = new Time(Time.getCurrentTimezone());
DBAdapter myDB;
EditText title;
Button newTask;
EditText description;
EditText routine;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    title = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextTask);
    description = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editDescriptionTask);
    routine = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editRoutineTask);
    newTask = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonNew);

    newTask.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, MenuActivity.class));
        }
    });

    openDB();
    populateListView();
    listViewItemClick();
    listViewItemLongClick();

}

private void openDB() {
    myDB = new DBAdapter(this);
    myDB.open();
}

public void populateListView() {
    Cursor cursor = myDB.getAllRows();

    String[] fromFieldNames = new String[] {
            DBAdapter.KEY_ROWID,DBAdapter.KEY_TASK,DBAdapter.KEY_DESCRIPTION
    };

    int[] toViewIDs = new int[] {
            R.id.textViewItemNumber, R.id.textViewItemTask, R.id.textViewItemDescription
    };

    SimpleCursorAdapter myCursorAdapter;
    myCursorAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(getBaseContext(),R.layout.item_layout,cursor,fromFieldNames,toViewIDs,0);
    ListView myList = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listViewTasks);
    myList.setAdapter(myCursorAdapter);
}

private void updateTask(long id) {
    Cursor cursor = myDB.getRow(id);
    if(cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        String task = title.getText().toString();
        today.setToNow();
        String date = today.format("%Y-%M-%D %H:%M:%S");
        myDB.updateRow(id, task, date);
    }

    cursor.close();
}

private void listViewItemClick() {
    ListView myList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listViewTasks);
    myList.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int arg2, long id) {
            updateTask(id);
            populateListView();
            displayToast(id);
        }
    });
}

public void onClick_AddTask(View v) {
    today.setToNow();
    String timeStamp = today.format("%Y-%M-%D %H:%M:%S");
    if(!TextUtils.isEmpty(title.getText().toString())) {
        myDB.insertRow(title.getText().toString(), timeStamp, description.getText().toString(), routine.getText().toString());
    }
    populateListView();
}

public void onClick_DeleteTasks(View v) {
    myDB.deleteAll();
    populateListView();
}

private void listViewItemLongClick() {
    ListView myList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listViewTasks);
    myList.setOnItemLongClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long id) {
            myDB.deleteRow(id);
            populateListView();

            return false;
        }
    });
}

private void displayToast(long id) {
    Cursor cursor = myDB.getRow(id);
    if(cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        long idDB = cursor.getLong(DBAdapter.COL_ROWID);
        String task = cursor.getString(DBAdapter.COL_TASK);
        String date = cursor.getString(DBAdapter.COL_DATE);

        String message = "ID: " + idDB + "\n" + "Task: " + task + "\n" + "Date: " + date;

        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, message, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
    cursor.close();
}

@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    closeDB();
}

private void closeDB() {
    myDB.close();
}
```

}

Second Activity :

```
import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

public class MenuActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

Button save;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_menu);

    save = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonAddTask);
    save.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            startActivity(new Intent(MenuActivity.this, MainActivity.class));
        }
    });
}
```

}

Comment: Your logcat is irrelevant. That's only system logs.

Comment: Put the code in the question, avoid linking them out. If the links die/break, this question serve little help to anyone.

Answer (score 0):

Check what `insertRow` returns. If it returns less than 1, this means you cant insert.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that the ListView is empty.

Look very closely at PopulateListView():

```
public void populateListView() {
    Cursor cursor = myDB.getAllRows();

    String[] fromFieldNames = new String[] {
            DBAdapter.KEY_ROWID,DBAdapter.KEY_TASK,DBAdapter.KEY_DESCRIPTION
    };

    int[] toViewIDs = new int[] {
            R.id.textViewItemNumber, R.id.textViewItemTask, R.id.textViewItemDescription
    };

    SimpleCursorAdapter myCursorAdapter;
    myCursorAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(getBaseContext(),R.layout.item_layout,cursor,fromFieldNames,toViewIDs,0);
    ListView myList = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listViewTasks);
    myList.setAdapter(myCursorAdapter);
}
```

**Some Clues**

First of all, you keep initializing the myList ListView, every time the method is called.  Do that one time when the class is instantiated.  Why?  Because you may be overwriting the list with an empty listview or something.  I can't tell but it's a clue.

Second, I don't see how new items are added to your ListView.  I see you setting the Adapter each time, but I don't see an add.  Maybe that's just me, but it's something to look at.

Now, here's some quick code I have that updates a ListView

In OnCreate() -- (one-time initialization) I have :

```
listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.mainListView);
adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, listViewItems);
listView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Then later, in other code where I want to add items I have code like the following:

```
  // Add three generic items 
  for (int x = 0;x <=2;x++){
           adapter.add("test : " + String.valueOf(x));
        }
   // let the adapter / view know the item list has changed so UI is updated.
   adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

This may not be the answer but may help you get there.
Good luck.

Comment: Thank you very much for your time, I did try everything you mentioned but as I said, the problem turned out to be stupid. It seems that in the XML on the save button, witch is in the menu layout, I tried to call the onClick_AddTask function in the main java file. I now need to figure out how to acces a function from the main java file from a different layout file but I guess that is for a different question.